# Trying to prove that $\varphi(s)$ is related to prime numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, solution-verification, prime-numbers, riemann-zeta, euler-product

My goal is to show that $\varphi(s)$ is related to prime numbers.

Define $$ \varphi(s)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty \big(e^{-n^{-s}}-1\big). $$

Note that $e^x-1=\sum_{k\geq 1} x^k/k!$ for all $x$. One can use this expansion to express $\varphi(s)$ as a sum of Riemann zeta functions:

$$ \varphi(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{k!} \zeta(sk)$$

This means $\varphi(s)$ can be expressed as a sum of products of primes:

$$ \varphi(s)=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}\bigg(\prod_{\text{p prime}} \frac{1}{1-p^{-sk}{}}\bigg)$$

> Is this correct?

Comment: Sure, it is correct. Not sure if it proves it is “related to primes” in a useful way.

Comment: In particular, you get similar functions with $\sum_n\left(e^{n^{-s}}-1\right).$ or $\sum (f(n^{-s})-f(0))$ for any $f$ analytic on a ball of radius $>1$ around $0.$